# How to Render Div Conditionally Depending on the Length of Values Returned

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

I have a list function and I would like to use the number of length it gets to conditionally render a div. If its length is 0 then the div with "No Data Added" text is rendered, else the div with data table will be rendered. I tried to use ternary operator for this, but I'm not sure how it's done correctly.

Here's my code:

```
      ({this.props.myList.length === 0 ?
              <div>
                <span>
                  No Data Added
                </span>
                Please add data by using the "Add" button.
              </div>
            :
            <div>
              <CustomizedTable 
              tableProperties={this.props.detailsTable} 
              />
            </div>
        })
```

Here's my solution to the issue:

```
       {
          this.props.detailsTable.length <= 0 ?
             (<div>
                <span>
                  No Data Added
                </span>
                Please add data by using the "Add" button.
              </div>)
            : (
            <div>
              <CustomizedTable 
              tableProperties={this.props.detailsTable} 
              />
            </div>)
        }
```

Comment: That looks fine, what *specifically* is the issue you're having?

Comment: @Jayce444 , it's showing the length and the operators in my interface and not returning the div based on the length it returned. All divs are still displayed.

Comment: All divs means, both  No Data Added and `<CustomizedTable ` is displayed? Even if logic fails only one of above should display

Comment: Yes both are being displayed @kiranvj

Comment: That should never happen, can you remove the starting `(` and ending `)`. Also check if you are editing the correct file and build is successfully

Comment: That's not how ternary operator works, it's an either/or operator. Are you able to give more context for your code, preferably a sandbox which recreates the issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I already removed the opening and closing parenthesis. I've changed the props where length is returned to the one I used in tableProperties. Also did some changes with the formatting. Updated my post with the solution.

Comment: Your edited version is looking for length LESS THAN 0, which will always be false.

Comment: Hi @LindaPaiste, it's "<= 0" (less than OR equal 0). It means that it will be true if the length is already greater than 0.

Comment: @Xev It shows up with a line break after the < on my phone so I didn’t notice the = on the next line ‍♀️